# findChild returns None with custom widget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have created a custom Qt widget in Python and managed to get it to load into the form at runtime however when I try and use findChild to grab it back of the form instance I get `None` back.

The widget is loaded and I can see it if I print out the names and objects on the form:

```
DEBUG:root:<PyQt4.QtGui.QCheckBox object at 0x11358030>
DEBUG:root:Near_Other_Infrastructure
DEBUG:root:<PyQt4.QtGui.QCheckBox object at 0x113582B8>
DEBUG:root:photo
DEBUG:root:<imagewidget.QMapImageWidget object at 0x113586A8>
```

This is the code:

```
images = self.forminstance.findChild(QMapImageWidget)
```

**Update:**

Seems doing this works:

```
images = self.forminstance.findChild(QWidget, "photo")
```

and it returns  `DEBUG:root:<imagewidget.QMapImageWidget object at 0x113586A8>`

although I would really perfer to just get the control via the type without using the name.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could we see the line you used to load your widget into the form?

Comment: I'm loading it using QUiLoader() and the load method.

Comment: I encountered this also.  Might it be a bug in Qt or PyQt?  Did you try self.forminstance.findChild(QMapImageWidget, "photo").  That is, what worked for you is a workaround and maybe just luck.  Your original code should work too.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.

One easy solution is to find a non-custom base class and cast.

```
Custom* ptr = dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(root->findChild<QWidget*>("MyWidgetName"));
if (ptr)
{
    //...whatever
}
```